# C++ template function problem with concreating

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

i wrote template function with 3 parameters, T - type of array, FUNC - function that return and get T as parameter, and N as size of array.
I get compilation error telling pretty much nothing :"Failed to specialize function template".

```
template<typename T,T* (*FUNC)(T), int N>
void process(T array[])
{
    for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        array[i] = FUNC(array[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    double a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    process<double, sin, 4>(a); 
    for (auto x : a)
        std::cout << x << " "; // 0.841471 0.909297 0.14112 -0.756802
}
```

Comment: Is `sin` your own function or a standard function?  What is the exact error text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sin` does not match the second template parameter. Change the function declaration to

```
template<typename T, T (*FUNC)(T), int N>
//                ^^ T, not T*
```

Comment: Thanks, i wrote * as pointer function and didn't realised that i gave two asterisk. Thanks very much